# Как запустить exe без командного строка в node.js через pkg?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

Я использую библиотеку pkg чтобы собрать exe. Мне не нужна командная строка, мне нужно чтобы она запускалась тихо без окна

Comment: Т.е. выполнить запуск команды в фоновом режиме? Возможно тут ты найдешь ответ - https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.b316fa7c-6454f598-484b7549-74722d776562/https/superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background

Comment: я так сделал start "" program, start /B "" program
все равно не помогло..

Comment: Там есть и другие варианты запуска... Но возможно не все можно запускать в фоновом режиме.

Comment: Я использую пока что start /min "" programm

Comment: Создайте службу и запускайте ее

Comment: Пытался, не создается или я не понял как